# How to recover data from truncated table in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I accidentally truncated 1 table in postgreSQL less than 18 hours ago. I have no backup for that data and I really need it back.

Comment: You maybe out of luck. Truncate will remove all the rows and free up the disk space, unless you have disc backups.

Comment: I have no disc back ups